# how to run celery flower with config file?

Tags: celery, config, flower

For my project. I want to use flower config file to instead of use command line options.

But I write a file named flowerconfig.py, like follows:

```
# RabbitMQ management
broker_api = 'http://user:passwd@localhost:15672/api/'

# Enable debug logging
logging = 'DEBUG'

# view address
address = '0.0.0.0'
port = 10006

basic_auth = ["user:passwd"]

persistent = True
db = "var/flower_db"
```

But when I run flower with the command `flower --conf=flowerconfig`. I found this broker not work.

I replace the command with `celery flower -A celery_worker.celery_app --conf=flowerconfig`. celery_worker is my celery file.

the broker is running normally.  but still the flowerconfig basic auth not work.

So I don't know if flower support file config. or other methods.

the versions:

- flower==0.9.2
- celery==4.2.1

Comment: finally，I found this config run normally on ubuntu server....... I will do some thing to find why?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a bash script to run. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
celery -A project flower \
    --basic_auth=monitor:password \
    --persistent=True \
    --max_tasks=9999 \
    -l info \
    --address=0.0.0.0 \
    --broker=redis://localhost:6379/0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually `flowerconfig` could work.  I did not reproduce the error on other machine. hh, Maybe just an accident.